# How to avoid duplicates while insert record using stored procedure...?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here is the Procedure that I have used........

```
CREATE procedure AcademicDetailsInsert
     @CandidateId int,
     @DegreeIDs varchar(25),
     @Board_Universities varchar(200),
     @YearsOfPassing varchar(50),
     @Percentages varchar(50)
As
    set NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        select @ReturnValue = 0

        IF EXISTS (SELECT ITEM AS DegID 
                   FROM [SplitString](@DegreeIDs,','))
            INSERT INTO [AcademicDetails] ([CandidateID], [DegreeId], [Board_University], [Year_Of_Passing], [Percentage])  
                SELECT  
                   @CandidateID, 
                   DegID.ITEM, Board_Uni.Item, YOfPass.ITEM,
                   Perc.ITEM
                FROM    
                   [splitString](@DegreeIDs, ',') DegID,
                   [splitString](@Board_Universities, ',') Board_Uni,
                   [splitString](@YearsOfPassing, ',') YOfPass,         
                   [splitString](@Percentages, ',') Perc
                WHERE
                   DegID.ITEM NOT IN (SELECT DegreeID
                                      FROM AcademicDetails
                                      WHERE CandidateID = @CandidateID)                 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT    
           ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERROR_NO,
           ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERROR_MSG,
           ERROR_LINE() AS ERROR_LINE_NO
    END CATCH    
END
```

And this is the code I used to run procedure...

```
EXEC AcademicDetailsInsert 1,'2,3','NMU,IND','2005,2008','66.33,71.65'
```

And here is the result..

```
1   2   nmu 2005    66.33
1   2   nmu 2008    66.33
1   2   nmu 2005    23.65
1   2   nmu 2008    23.65
1   2   nasik   2005    66.33
1   2   nasik   2008    66.33
1   2   nasik   2005    23.65
1   2   nasik   2008    23.65
1   3   nmu 2005    66.33
1   3   nmu 2008    66.33
1   3   nmu 2005    23.65
1   3   nmu 2008    23.65
1   3   nasik   2005    66.33
1   3   nasik   2008    66.33
1   3   nasik   2005    23.65
1   3   nasik   2008    23.65
```

When I pass detail for two record for single candidate it give different result

But instead of two record I get repeated record inserted. `SplitString` function is used for spliting function to split the degreeid, different university names and passing year and percentages.

How can I avoid that...?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 has [table valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), which I would use here instead of parsing the strings.

Comment: You are doing `CROSS JOIN` in your `SELECT`. That's why you are getting more records than needed.

Comment: So how can I avoid CROSS JOIN to insert that two record..?

Comment: Somehow you need to build one (temporary) table that would contain four columns (`DegID, Board_Uni, YOfPass, Perc`) and two rows with values from the given strings and then `SELECT` from this table.

Comment: I think it is impossible to get a guaranteed correct result using the `SplitString` function that you have. The function returns a table with one column `Item` and you call it four times independently. So, you are getting four different tables. The order of rows in each table is **not defined**, which means that there is no way you can put them together in one table and get consistent result. Either use table valued parameter, or change the `SplitString` function to process all four strings together.

Comment: Alternatively, you can still have four independent calls to the `SplitString` function, but change the `SplitString` function to return a table with two columns: `Row number` and `Item`. `Row number` would define the order inside the generated table. Then you could join these four generated tables together on the `Row number` to make the final table with the data to insert.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir Baranov, It works..! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You Have done the `Cross Join` so results are like that

Try using the below code,Hope it will work

```
ALTER procedure AcademicDetailsInsert
@CandidateId int,
@DegreeIDs varchar(25),
@Board_Universities varchar(200),
@YearsOfPassing varchar(50),
@Percentages varchar(50)
As
set NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
select @ReturnValue = 0
IF EXISTS  
(  
    SELECT ITEM AS DegID 
    FROM [SplitString](@DegreeIDs,',')
)
INSERT INTO [AcademicDetails]  
(     
    [CandidateID],  
    [DegreeId],
    [Board_University],
    [Year_Of_Passing],
    [Percentage] 
) 

 SELECT CandidateID,DegID,Board_Uni,YOfPass,Perc FROM 
 (
SELECT   


     @CandidateID AS CandidateID,
      SUBSTRING(@DegreeIDs,0,CHARINDEX(',',@DegreeIDs)-1) AS DegID ,
      SUBSTRING(@Board_Universities,0,CHARINDEX(',',@Board_Universities)-1) AS Board_Uni ,
      SUBSTRING(@YearsOfPassing,0,CHARINDEX(',',@YearsOfPassing)-1) AS YOfPass,
      SUBSTRING(@Percentages,0,CHARINDEX(',',@Percentages)-1)  AS Perc

      UNION
     SELECT  @CandidateID AS  CandidateID,


      SUBSTRING(@DegreeIDs,CHARINDEX(',',@DegreeIDs),Len(@DegreeIDs))  AS DegID,
      SUBSTRING(@Board_Universities,CHARINDEX(',',@Board_Universities),Len(@DegreeIDs)) AS Board_Uni,
      SUBSTRING(@YearsOfPassing,CHARINDEX(',',@YearsOfPassing),Len(@DegreeIDs)) AS YOfPass ,
      SUBSTRING(@Percentages,CHARINDEX(',',@Percentages),Len(@DegreeIDs))  AS Perc



     ) AS RandomTable


where   DegID not IN  (    SELECT DegreeID
                                FROM AcademicDetails
                                WHERE CandidateID = @CandidateID
                            )               
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERROR_NO,
          ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERROR_MSG,
          ERROR_LINE() AS ERROR_LINE_NO
END CATCH    
END
```

Comment: It is very likely, that if it was known that procedure always takes exactly two values in the comma-separated strings, the procedure would just have normal parameters and there will be no need for parsing the strings. It is very likely, that this procedure is expected to work when given strings have more than two values separated by commas and the possible number of values is not known in advance.

Comment: in that case ,question should mention what it should be like, what i simply assume by his code, that if he needs more than 1 value (say n) then there should be validation for each paramters to have equal number of comma separated values.